# WCF with SSL- not finding localhost

Tags: wcf, ssl

I'm trying to get WCF to use SSL with ANYTHING for FIVE DAYS now. I've gone through countless walkthroughs, generated more certificates than a mail order diploma company, even tried hot fixes. After working with MS dev tools since VB1, I am now considering flipping burgers as a career option. WCF, as far as I can see, is a complete lemon.

Anyway, to get to my actual question: If I run through this walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648840.aspx

I get to step 11 (adding the service reference) and get "**There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address**".

Details of the error gives: There was an error downloading 'https://localhost/SSL6/Service.svc'.
**Unable to connect to the remote server**
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:443

I'm using VS2008 on Windows 7 with IIS7. I followed the walkthrough exactly (apart from step 5 which was different on IIS7- I went into "SSL Settings" for the VD), so it shows my config (yes I've used httpsGetEnabled and mexHttpsBinding).

Anyone care to save my sanity and job?

---

**EDIT**: If I go into IIS, select the VD in content view, right-click on the svc file and browse, I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Chrome gives "Google Chrome could not connect to localhost".

IE troubleshooting gives "the remote device or resource won't accept the connection".

If I browse using the IP address rather than using localhost via http, it says that it's secured with https ok. If I browse using the IP and https, I get HTTP error 503. The service is unavailable.

So it looks to me like a DNS issue combined with... something. 
When I try to just run the service site project, I get "Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to connect to the web server. Verify that the web server is running and that incoming HTTP requests are not blocked by a firewall". I've checked the firewall and it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally cracked it. There were at least three issues at play.

1) A DNS issue of some kind with localhost. It's still unresolved on my machine, but I can work around it by using the IP addy.

2) Another issue may have been that apparently, WCF doesn't work with IIS 7 OOTB. So you need to run command prompt as administrator, and run the following command -

"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r -y

3) After I got through the certificate stuff I was still getting HTTP error 503, "Service unavailable". That ended up being leftovers from my previous attempts, still listening to ports:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webtopics/archive/2010/02/17/a-not-so-common-root-cause-for-503-service-unavailable.aspx

So to get a hello world level service happening with WCF and SSL took me a whole week, and in my travels I discovered many pilgrims who had taken about the same amount of time. Microsoft: You have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IIS or self hosting? If you're using IIS, it sounds like it's incorrectly configured, because it seems it's not accepting connections on port 443; I guess you're probably missing a protocol binding (https to port 443). There's a detailed discussion of setting up SSL on IIS7 [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-setup-ssl-on-iis-7/) that might be useful.

Of course, you could easily verify this using the browser, you should be able to connect to the site using SSL from it.

Comment: IIS. I'd already gone through the steps in the link you posted :(

Comment: If you can't connect using 127.0.0.1, it's not a DNS issue. I'm reasonably sure you've got IIS setup incorrectly and it's not listening on port 443 (or else, you've got some weird firewall blocking request to the local host).

Comment: BTW, easy way to verify if IIS is listening on port 443: a) use netstat -an and look for something on that port, or damn, just use telnet.exe and try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had this error occur, I have found it very useful to run the service from Visual Studio to get additional information.  Right-click on the service, and then select Debug -> Start New Instance from the pop-up menu.  VS will launch the service using the WcfTestClient.exe.

WcfTestClient will display all the services and endpoints in your service project.  A healthy launch will list your services in the a panel on the left, and provide a Start Page tab in a panel on the right.  What will happen in your case, however, is that you'll get a list of services in a panel on the *top* and an "Additional Information" box along the bottom.  Your problem service(s) will have a Status of Error.

Click on a problem service in the upper panel, and the Additional Information box will fill with an error message and stack trace.  The message will tell you exactly what that problem mex (metadata exchange) address is.  That may be enough of a hint for you to solve the problem.  If not, post the Additional Information here and I'll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: The walkthrough gets you to use a service web site project, so you can't right click and debug it. I'll add a service app proj, copy my code over and try it.